# How to pass Facebook access token from one activity to another activity

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

My main activity contains the code to login to the facebook. Facebook LoginResult gives the access token as response.  Next activity  contains the graph API call to get users posts which needs access token. How can we pass the access token from that  activity to another activity.

Heres the code that gets access token with loginResult.

```
 FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callBack=new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()    {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        System.out.println(profile.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement I think you need access token to call facebook graph API. In that case rather passing access token from one activity to another you can use

public static AccessToken getCurrentAccessToken()

of AccessToken class. Here is the link to [AccessToken](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessToken/) class. If you want AccessToken as String you can use.

public String getToken()

Comment: I have AccesstokenTracker object on the mainactivity and onAccessTokenChanged method I have have accessToken = newToken given by the parameter of the process. WillgetCurrentAccessToken method give new token when old one is expired and tracked by AcessTokenTracker?

`code`(
    AccessTokenTracker accessTracker=new AccessTokenTracker() {
            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {
                accessToken=newToken;
            }
        };
)